# Pandas. Set a column name as parameter

Tags: python, pandas

Im working with pandas and I want to set a column of the query as parameter. I try this:

```
res_estacion_b = pd.read_sql("SELECT date, :column FROM table_1 WHERE date BETWEEN 
    TO_DATE(:date_ini, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AND 
    TO_DATE(:date_end, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')",
    con=db, params={'date_ini': inicio, 'date_end': fin, 'column': condition.name})

The result is:

     date               :COLUMN
0  2009-01-01 00:00:00  PARK_DEF
1  2009-01-01 00:10:00  PARK_DEF
2  2009-01-01 00:20:00  PARK_DEF
3  2009-01-01 00:30:00  PARK_DEF
4  2009-01-01 00:40:00  PARK_DEF
5  2009-01-01 00:50:00  PARK_DEF
```

Instead of getting the column value, I get the column name. 
Is it possible to get the values?

Comment: :column doesn't seem to be replaced with the content of condition.name. try to replace the variables in the string in advance like this: str="SELECT date, {coumn} ..".format(column=condition.name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply replace the column name in a string in advance:

```
str = "SELECT date, {column} FROM table_1 WHERE date BETWEEN 
    TO_DATE(:date_ini, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AND 
    TO_DATE(:date_end, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')".format(column=condition.name)
res_estacion_b = pd.read_sql(str, con=db, params={'date_ini': inicio, 'date_end': fin})
```

Comment: That's work, but is correct? I mean, I want to use the features of Pandas for doing that and the use of format for sql I dont think that's the best way. It's better use placeholders, right?

Comment: Its a solution to the Problem.